# How can I make a button navigate my page to a text field on a page when I click edit in .net maui

Tags: c#, maui

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CarPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { nameof(CarItems),carItem }});
```

this removes the car details but goes on to edit the car parts, I want it to keep current car details but allow me to edit the parts

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(CarPage), true, new Dictionary<string, object> { { nameof(CarItems),carItem }});
```

this navigates to car page, and goes to the edit car item but it removes the car details

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  The single line of code you posted doesn’t really tell us anything about what you’re doing

Comment: You can refer to official doc: [.NET MAUI Shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/navigation?view=net-maui-7.0). Wish it can help you.